# how to convert gif/webp buffer into mp4 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I want to convert gif(bufffer) into mp4(buffer) in node.js
and saw some solutions using ffmpeg library.

But, ffmpeg library, only supports converting in file format.
How to do that??

+) I am developing web scraper, and get the gif response and convert it into
mp4 format and finally upload to aws s3.

Here is the code I will want to do (pseudo)

```
var ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
var ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);

const gifResponse = ....  # type is buffer. <Buffer ....>
# const bufferSize = gifResponse.length

# From below, I am struggling with, I don't know how to do converting... 
# Any library doesn't matter. 
# Just I want to convert gif to mp4, finally I want to get the mp4 buffer. 

const convertedBuffer = ffmpeg
  .input(gifResponse)
  .on('error', (err) => {console.log(err)})
  .on('end', () => {...})
  .noAudio()
  .ouput('....')
  .run()

# convertedBuffer(mp4) I want to get
```

Comment: _"But FFmpeg library only supports converting in **file** format. How to do that?"_ You mean like replacing an expected file _path_ with a file _bytes_ (_eg:_ some array/buffer/blob)? Did you try creating a (virtual file) path pointing to your bytes data? For that you can use Node's [createObjectURL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlcreateobjecturlblob). First create the path ID when all GIF bytes exists. Example: `gifBytes_ID = URL.createObjectURL( gifResponse );` then later in your code you can try running FFmpeg with `.input( resolveObjectURL( gifBytes_ID) )`. Ask about what you've tried.

Comment: I think it's not working.. 
first, URL.createObjectURL(input) // buffer is not allowed for the input.  
so I change it to blob. but still not working. 

>> Error: Invalid input

Comment: What is your `input` exactly? You pseudo-code only has `FFmpeg.input` as nearest thing with that name... Use `URL.createObjectURL( gifResponse.data );` or whatever will get you the buffer (actual GIF bytes) inside the HTTP response.

Comment: PS: `var myBlob = new Blob( [ gifResponse.data ], {type: "application/octet-stream"} );` then followed by `var myID = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL( myBlob );` would work in browser JS so you need the equivalent result from NodeJS coding. Where `myID` is then later used as input in your FFmpeg file path. You want to use bytes instead of file then use **createObjectURL** because it was designed for that purpose. It will have to work for you somehow...

Comment: PPS: Regarding _"but still not working. >> `Error: Invalid input`"_ What is not working exactly? For a **faster answer** (from anyone) please show a **testable code** that can recreate your error. Not obvious what is your **input** (a `Fetch` result? if yes, let's confirm first that you got data in correct format etc).... If blob part is not working then the input might be incorrect, if FFmpeg is not working then blob might be used incorrectly. What does _"not working"_ mean here?